# How to modify value when deserializing

Tags: json

Brothers, how to modify the value of the specified field (annotation) during deserialization, just like the ContextValueFilter of fastjson during serialization

just like the ContextValueFilter of fastjson during serialization

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] a good question and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to the question and reformulate it (preferably with your code, the provided input and the expected output) in order to get a (useful) answer. Before posting a question, [search](/search) the site and make sure that a similar question has not already been answered. Show what you have tried and where you got stuck to maximize the chances to get help.

Comment: In its current state, this question will be closed soon because it is not clear what are you asking about. If it is closed before you manage to improve it, you can always create a new question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.